# Why does object get destroyed after using it several times?

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm using Get-CMApplication to retrieve an application. The result gets stored to $App. I can use $App several times until I use `$Deployment = $App | Get-CMApplicationDeployment` to retrieve all deployments that are linked to this application. After this line of code the variable $App is empty.

Instead of using `$App | Get-CMApplicationDeployment` I could retrieve the original object again like so: `Get-CMApplication "MyApp 1.0" | Get-CMApplicationDeployment`. But I want to limit the queries to the SCCM server, there is no need to query two times the same.

```bsh
$App = Get-CMApplication -Name "System Center Configuration Manager Console 5.1902.1085.2600"
Write-Output "This is the app: $($App.LocalizedDisplayName)"
$Deployment = $App | Get-CMApplicationDeployment
$Deployment.Count
Write-Output "This is the app: $($App.LocalizedDisplayName)"
if ($null -eq $App) {Write-Output "Yes, it's NULL!"}
if ($App) {Write-Output "Yes, it's available!"}
if ($App -eq "") {Write-Output "Yes, it's empty!"}
$App | Get-Member
```

Cloning the object first and using the clone for Get-CMApplicationDeployment allows me to use $App later in my program.

```bsh
$AppTemp = $App.PsObject.Copy()
$Deployment = $AppTemp | Get-CMApplicationDeployment
```

I would expect to be able to use $App all over my program, but it seems that using Get-CMApplicationDeployment kills it. Even Get-Member returns an error: The following exception occurred while retrieving members: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I don't understand why the object $App gets killed.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are running into your issue is, you are trying to pipe `Get-CMApplication` into `Get-CMApplicationDeployment`

Using your example, this should allow you to assign the deployment to `$Deployment` and the app to `$App`:

```
$App  = Get-CMApplication -Name "System Center Configuration Manager Console 5.1902.1085.2600"
$Deployment = Get-CMApplicationDeployment -Name $App.LocalizedDisplayName
$Deployment.Count
Write-Output "This is the app: $($App.LocalizedDisplayName)"
if ($null -eq $testApp) {Write-Output "Yes, it's NULL!"}
if ($testApp) {Write-Output "Yes, it's available!"}
if ($testApp -eq "") {Write-Output "Yes, it's empty!"}
$Deployment
```

Comment: Of course you can. Check out MS docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/get-cmapplicationdeployment?view=sccm-ps)
What you are doing is querying ALL deployments and then filter against the app name. This takes a very long time.

Comment: @FabianS. thanks for the documentation. I was unaware that `Name` was an alias for `ApplicationName`. I have updated the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

We could change

```
$Deployment = $App | Get-CMApplicationDeployment
```

to

```
$Deployment = Get-CMApplicationDeployment -Name $App.LocalizedDisplayName
```

This should preserve the objects in $APP.

Best Regards,
Ray

Comment: This is interesting. I missed that!
What I tried was this:
```$Deployment = Get-CMApplicationDeployment -InputObject $App```

This will destroy the object as well.

But using ```-Name``` works. Of course this creates a new query to the server. So, seems that there is no way around a second query.